# Books on calculus of variations and|or integral equations

Tags: book-recommendation, calculus-of-variations, integral-equations

I want to find a good textbooks on calculus of variations and|or integral equations. It would be awesome if:

- the textbook has a lot of difficult exercises explained or has a problem book;
- it starts from the basis and goes to really difficult concepts;
- it has examples from such fields as electrodynamics or radiotechnics;

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Not really a textbook, but the Faculty of Khan YouTube channel has a great series on Calculus of Variations, though only really a introduction playlist covering the euler-langrange equation and the beltrami identity along with some examples and derivations.

Comment: Try Bernard Dacorogna "Introduction to the Calculus of Variations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try "Calculus of Variations" by Gelfand and Fomin. From the author preface:

> Our aim is to give a treatment of the ele­ments of the calculus of variations in a form which is both easily understandable and sufficiently modem. Considerable attention is devoted to physical applica­tions of variational methods, e.g., canonical equations, variational principles of mechanics and conservation laws.